# Cannot install through2-map

Tags: linux, node.js

When I try to install through2-map using the command:

```
user1@ubuntu:~/nodetest1$ npm install through2-map
```

I get error message:

```
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'request'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
npm ERR!     at require (module.js:373:17)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/fetch.js:5:15)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-34-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "through2-map"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user1/nodetest1
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user1/nodetest1/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am new to node and have no idea why is this happening or how can I solve it. Please help

UPDATE: Additional messages from npm-debug file

```
user1@ubuntu:~/nodetest1$ cat /home/user1/nodetest1/npm-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'through2-map' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.15
3 info using node@v0.11.10-pre
4 error Error: Cannot find module 'request'
4 error     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
4 error     at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
4 error     at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
4 error     at require (module.js:373:17)
4 error     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/fetch.js:5:15)
4 error     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
4 error     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
4 error     at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
4 error     at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
4 error     at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
5 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
5 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
5 error or email it to:
5 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
6 error System Linux 3.8.0-34-generic
7 error command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "through2-map"
8 error cwd /home/user1/nodetest1
9 error node -v v0.11.10-pre
10 error npm -v 1.3.15
11 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
user1@ubuntu:~/nodetest1$
```

Comment: It installs fine for me, on OSX.  I suggest you post relevant parts of the additional log referred to in the error messsage.

Comment: Honestly with the 'cannot find module request' seems like npm or node is broken.  Can you install other modules, e.g. try installing something very common, e.g. express - use 'npm install express'

Comment: What version of node.js and how you installed it might be useful too.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu using the same command. Through2-map doesn't even have the `request` dependency. Did you try to running `npm install request` before this by chance?

Comment: Version is v0.11.10-pre, downloaded source from github, configure/make/install

Comment: `npm install request` returns pretty much the same error.

Comment: You know this is a pre-release of the unstable branch right? You are learning node.js?  I would use the latest stable release - 0.10.22 or at most the latest unstable release.

Comment: I tried doing update as said on this post: http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs but the first line throws the same exception I get above. So it seems that I have a problem with npm. It worked fine earlier, I broke something, no idea what...

Comment: I believe the problem is with a missing package in the npm.js code, which prevents you from installing anything. Can you run `ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/` and check if request is shown?

Comment: @making3 Yes, request is on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You built this from source from the latest unreleased code on the unstable branch of node.js, followed by a failed upgrade of node using npm.   This may be a bug, or a problem introduced through an unusual upgrade performed on a pre-release version of the code.

Unless you need facilities in 0.11.x I would strongly recommend you use the latest stable release 0.10.22.

The most recent stable version is always shown prominently on the [node.js website](http://nodejs.org/).

If you want (or need to) build from source, once you've cloned the repo, you can use

```
git checkout v0.10.22
```

To get the right version before building.

If you want to switch around versions, I would also recommend using node version manager:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: That solved it. Thank you very much. (sorry can't upvote your answer, not enough rep)